# Wait for key after nautilus-actions in terminal

Tags: 13.10, nautilus, nautilus-actions

I need to execute a script from the `nautilus-actions` and then wait for any input from the user, who has to read what the script has done before the terminal disappears.

This is my current `nautilus-actions` configuration:

- Runtime execution: `gnome-terminal -x sh -c COMMAND`
- Make executable:

  - Path: `gksudo`
  - Parameters: `chmod +x %F`

This script makes a file executable (`+x`) but I'd like to actually see the `chmod` output, if any, before the terminal is closed. Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `read` (see man page of your shell) to make the terminal wait for the user to press a key to indicate they have read the output. Unfortunately, `read` from `dash` is rather limited, so I'd recommend using `bash` for this.

`read -s -n1 -p "Press any key to continue"` will print the prompt to the terminal (`-p`), wait for any key to be pressed (`-n1`) and finally exit without printing the entered key (`-s`).

Adding that to your script gives your users all the time they need.

**Update**: To integrate the above into *nautilus-actions*, create a bash script you can then use as action in the configuration dialog.

The script would have to look something like the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
gksu chmod +x $1
read -s -n1 -p "Press any key to continue"
```

Calling that script with a file name as first parameter – just like you did before with `chmod` – will set the executable bit for that file, then wait for user input.

Comment: I have read about, well, `read`, but how can I integrate it into `nautilus-actions`?

Comment: Added some information on how to do that to the post.

Comment: I imagined that would be a solution; but can't I do this in the single command passed by `nautilus-actions`? I have already tried `thecommand -param; read -s -n1 -p "Press any key to continue"` but that does not work.

Comment: From what I can tell, *nautilus-actions* does not support multiple commands. Thus, more complex actions have to be wrapped in a script like the one in my post.